# MySQL getting count of a column from another table in a sub-query

Tags: mysql

Does anyone have any idea why the CASE WHEN() always return "Yes" even though there are some data records (by RecordID) that do NOT have an entry in the data_records_ga table?

I am at this point in time not sure why the very outer `SELECT * FROM (...) AS X` is there, but my problem is in the inner `SELECT data_records.RecordID, (...` and its associated sub-query.

I am expecting to see "No" for records that do not have the condition of the sub-query met, inserted into the "Completed" field.

```
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT
            data_records.RecordID,
            (
                CASE WHEN (
                    SELECT COUNT(drga.Comment) AS count
                    FROM `data_records_ga` drga
                    INNER JOIN `data_records` dr
                    ON dr.RecordID = drga.RecordID
                    WHERE drga.FieldName = 'GA_completed'
                    AND drga.Comment = 1
                    AND dr.RecordID = drga.RecordID
                    HAVING COUNT(drga.Comment) > 0
                ) > 0
                THEN 'Yes'
                ELSE 'No'
                END
            ) AS Completed,
        FROM `data_records`
        LEFT JOIN data_records_ga on data_records.RecordID = data_records_ga.RecordID
        GROUP BY RecordID ORDER BY RecordID
    ) AS X
```

Comment: Did you try to run subquery from the case separately? Also notice that `null` is not equals to anything usually.

Comment: This query is just too wrong for me to figure out what you are trying to do can you add sample data as text together with expected output please.

Comment: @Alexey, in some version of my attempts, I have. The above is probably (definitely?) wrong as I started to run out of ideas. At my attempt, I did get 244 records with the comment set to 1,which is what I expected, but using that, I got an error about the sub query returning more than one row, hence the attempt to try the 'group by' and/or 'having'.

Comment: @P.Salmon, I will when at computer if the proposed answer does not work. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to all who responded. The problem got resolved as per @reembank's answer. Very silly mistake from my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely because your subquery is not linked to its parent in any way, so you're only selecting rows that will give you 'Yes'. Try adding this line to the WHERE clause in your subquery:

```
AND dr.RecordID = data_records.RecordID
```

and removing:

```
AND dr.RecordID = drga.RecordID
```

The above line is redundant because you've already joined the tables together in your subquery.